# Are there any drawbacks to covering a carbon steel pan while seasoning to reduce smoke?

Tags: kitchen-safety, seasoning-pans, carbon-steel

I live in a house with poor ventilation. Often whenever I season my pan the smoke alarm goes off & a burnt oil smell lingers in the house for a few days.

I've considered covering my pan with a metal pot lid to reduce smoke, with a fan next to a window blowing to the outside. During seasoning, I occasionally move the pan in front of the fan, lifting the lid and letting the it suck the smoke outside before applying a new coat of oil & returning to the heat.

Are there any potential drawbacks to this method?

Should i be concerned with safety at all?

I've done it once and it seems to be working.

Comment: Lots of people overthink seasoning. Just use your pans.  I've got 5 awesome carbon steel pans.  I did an initial seasoning on the stove top, with just a couple of light coats of oil.  Then I just used the pans.  I use minimal soap, generally just wiping out, drying, and hitting with a light coat of oil.  Avoid acidic foods.  They just keep getting better.  No headaches.  Just requires patience.

Comment: Seconded. You do not need to “season” cookware, beyond giving it a quick sear with oil before you start using it. “Seasoned” is an adjective meaning “experienced” or “well-used”. It’s only recently that people decided it meant “you can’t use cast iron for real until you’ve watched YouTube videos about linseed oil”.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an oven and your pan is oven-safe (meaning all metal handles), you can follow [this guide from SeriousEats](https://www.seriouseats.com/how-to-season-carbon-steel-pans) and season your pan in the oven instead of over your burner. That should reduce the amount of smoke in your home significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there would be any negative effects in covering the pan to keep the smoke in the pan.  Would you then take the pan outside and let the smoke out?  Can you season the pan outside with a small burner instead of inside the house?  You could also make this the “dirty kitchen” where you would cook things that are too smelly or smokey to cook inside.